# What is "=- 1" in a python method's argument list?

Tags: python, arguments, default

On the following page: [subprocess.popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), in the argument list of `popen()` there is a "`pipesize=- 1`". Since it pops up at a few places, it does not seem to be a typo.

As for what this may be, however, so far eluded my curiosity.

What does the "`=- 1`" mean?

Comment: It means the default value is `-1`.

Comment: It's parsed the same as `pipesize = -1`. If you meant to decrement the value, it's `pipesize -= 1`.

Comment: @chepner It's not from code, it's in the parameter list documentation. It's just poor formatting.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a bug in whatever is generating the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is likely an error with the documentation. It should look like `pipesize = -1`. But, regardless, it is a default value for an argument.

## Parameters and Arguments in Functions

By default, all parameters in a function signature MUST be passed an argument when you call the function:

```py
def f(x):
    pass

f("argument for x")
```

The code above will successfully run without any errors. `x` is a required parameter of function `f`, and I correctly passed a positional argument to `x`.

### What if I don't pass an argument to a required parameter?

When given this code, it results in an exception called `TypeError`:

```py
def f(x):
    pass

f() # TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

This happens because, as stated above, `x` MUST be passed based on the current function signature of `f`.

### Specifying optional arguments

Now, I will provide a default value for parameter `x` in function `f`:

```py
def f(x=None):
    pass

f()
```

This code will also successfully run, like the first implementation of function `f`. But, here the function signature looks different and we didn't pass anything when we called `f`. `x=None` says that "if `x` isn't passed an argument in the function call to `f`, it should be passed `None` as an argument".

### Default vs. Non-Default Parameters

It is important to note that parameters with defaults MUST appear, in the function signature, after ALL required parameters:

```py
def f(x=None, y):
    pass
```

This implementation of `f` will result in `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`. It makes sense that default arguments would have to be specified, in the function signature, after ALL non-default arguments. If Python didn't raise an error for the syntactically incorrect function signature of `f` above, we could accidentally pass an argument to `x` instead of `y` when we do not want to.